# Reference ClientInstanceName in JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, devexpress

How can I reference cbAmount in javascript? I cannot seem to get it to work. (This is devexpress)

**aspx:**

```
 <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="ASPxCheckBox2" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="cbAmount" ClientEnabled="true">
         <ClientSideEvents CheckedChanged="function(s, e) {
            //  tbUserAmt.SetEnabled(!tbUserAmt.GetEnabled());
                radioClick(); }">  
         </ClientSideEvents>
    </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
```

**javascript:**

```
   function radioClick() {

    var val1 = 0;
    var isChecked = cbAmount.Checked;
    }
```

The debugger shows isChecked to be undefined. 
I have also tried:

> document.getByElementId("cbAmout").Checked 
>   document.getByElementId("ASPxCheckBox2").Checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cbAmount.GetChecked()`.

GetChecked method [documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientCheckBox_GetCheckedtopic).
For list of ASPxClientCheckBox members look [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientCheckBoxMembersTopicAll).